# Getting 404 error from fetch github single user based on input entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch github single user based on input entry.
I get 404 error even before i type inside the input i don't know why.
Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong in my code ?

The error i got :
XHRGET https://api.github.com/users/ [HTTP/2 404  142ms]

My code :

```
     import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
     import "./FormComponent.scss";

      const FormComponent = () => {
          const [user, setUser] = useState("");
          const [profile, setProfile] = useState([]);
          const submitForm = (e) => {
             e.preventDefault();
             setUser("");
          };
         useEffect(() => {
             let fetData = async () => {
             try {
                let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`);
                console.log(response);
                const users = await response.json();
                setProfile(users);
                    } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                  }
                 };
                fetData();
               }, []);

               return (
                 <div className="FormComponent">
                 <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                 <input
                     onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                     type="text"
                     value={user}
                    />
                {profile.map((e) => console.log(e))}
                <button>Search</button>
                </form>
                </div>
                );
               };
             export default FormComponent;
```

Comment: Because you are searching without a user specified, and that endpoint does not exist. useEffect executes at first without you having specified the user name.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i got your point. How i can rearrange it or fix the code any tip please ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are searching without a user specified, and that endpoint does not exist. useEffect executes at first without you having specified the user name.

Try this instead.

```
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import "./FormComponent.scss";

  const FormComponent = () => {
      const [user, setUser] = useState("");
      const [profile, setProfile] = useState([]);
      const submitForm = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         setUser("");
      };

      const fetchData = async (user) => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`);
        return await response.json()
      }

      const onInputChange = async (e) => {
        setUser(e.target.value);
        const users = await fetchData(e.target.value);
        setProfile(users);
      }

           return (
             <div className="FormComponent">
             <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
             <input
                 onChange={onInputChange}
                 type="text"
                 value={user}
                />
            {profile.map((e) => <p>{e}</p>)}
            <button>Search</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            );
           };
         export default FormComponent;
```

Comment: once you add this code i got an error :  {profile.map((e) => console.log(e))}.., also i was doing something wrong is that mapping inside the form, but even outside still got the same error which is weird

Comment: you cannot use `map` like that. in `map` you must return a value. Why do you need map? I updated the code.

Comment: i understand what you mean, but if you are updating a list of arrays, or the response which is a single user in an array form, don't you need to map to fetch the data on the screen ?

Comment: Yes, I understood what you were trying to do. The new code should do it.

Comment: unfortunatly it didnt cause in your code there is no mapping or fetching

Comment: `onInputChange` there is the fetching of data. Profiles is mapped into paragraphs